# "Changing" all existing and new row id's in MySQL without impacting application

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

My database has around 100 tables and anywhere from 1,000 to 20,000 rows per table. Each of the tables has a primary key called id - at the moment when referencing rows in a table I am simply using id, for example `www.domain.com/viewuser.php?id=3`

I am pretty sure I have no hardcoded references to row ID's in my code, they all reference either a POST value or a session ID set when the user logs in.

Is it easy to retrospectively change the id from auto increment integer to a unique alphanumeric id for all my existing tables without causing extensive recoding or altering existing queries etc? If so, how would I go about it?

My tow thought were to manually update all my tables but this would also require changing every insert as well? Could I do something with a unique_id table which sits between though I think this may require updating of all queries? Hoping there is an easy way to do this...

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: If you are worried about predictable IDs in the URL, you may consider encrypting/decrypting the GET ID to simplify your situation and avoid redoing all primary IDs (which is going to be huge and risky undertaking and may cause data corruption)

Comment: What you propose sounds like a really bad idea. Seems like a whole lot of effort, and there's a whole lot of things that can go wrong. (It's not the things we know about that bite us, it's those things we don't know about.) There would have to be some SIGNIFICANT (and measurable) benefit do doing something like this before I even considered embarking upon such an errand.

Comment: The application is multi company with sensitive data and some users are manipulating URL's and changing the id's to try to access data they should not - I am pretty sure I have coded to avoid this due to table and query structure but I want to add an additional layer of integrity by randomising the id's.

Comment: If the app has sensitive data, they should not be able to access it by changing the URLs to one with the right ID.  If they don't have permission to view the URL, the application should enforce that.  Don't rely on "obfuscated" id's or non-sequential IDs for this.  It doesn't solve the problem, only makes the end user have to work (slightly) harder to discover your URLs.

Comment: I can tell you from experience, you do not want to change unique ever-increasing integer Ids to alphanumeric ones. There are numerous performance issues. My company just got done spending a whole lot of man hours doing the opposite: converting all of our alphanumeric primary keys to integer ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randomizing the id values (changing them from auto_increment integers to alphanumeric) in the database doesn't really address the underlying problem.

Even if you manage to randomize and obfuscate the id values, users are still going to be able to access other user's data through URL manipulation. All you are going to achieve is to make it it "less likely" that any particular URL manipulation attempt will succeed at returning forbidden data.

If your app needs to PREVENT some users from seeing some data, then your app needs to provide a real mechanism for doing that.

Obfuscating ID values is going to be whole lot of work, and in the end, it won't accomplish what *really* needs to be done.

(see the comments from Sabeen Malik, drew010, Justin Swartsel,,, they are all "right on".)

---

If your application already implements a mechanism to prevent access to forbidden data, the obfuscation of ID values is not necessary.

The only place these ID values really need to obfuscated would be in the URL (or POST), and that can be achieved WITHOUT changing the existing database.  (See Sabeen Malik's comment; it's possible to encrypt/decrypt the id values sent to/from the browser... the big issue there is if there is javascript running in the browser that is depending on the id values being "orderable"...)

---

I understand this may not be the answer you were looking for in your original question. But I wouldn't undertake the effort to change from `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT` values absent a good reason to.

Comment: I do understand the need to ensure the application prevents unauthorised access and I am 99.9% confident it does but I wanted to add this as an additional layer on top of the application coding rather than trying to use it as the only way to prevent users from accessing data they shouldn't.

Comment: Its not about looking for a particular answer, the question has been answered ultimately - it is not easy to do, has performance implications and is not a good idea which I suspected but wanted to check hence asking. Happy not to do anything and just check and double check my queries etc to ensure only authorised users can access any given data.

Answer (score 1):

Without deep knowledge of your application, this is practically impossible to answer accurately. What i can tell you though is that everything CAN be done, but it depends on your code structure. Are you using a good MVC layout or a cheap blanket style code?

I sincerely hope you have a MVC like system where your models are all concentrated in a few file or it will become hell to maintain and make sure you got all the spots of the application ok.